# Searching an Enumerated Type

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

I am trying to use an Enumerated type as a reference to sort through a table of numbers.  So what I want to do is give a Method a number, the Method will take that number and use the Enumeration to decide what that number actually means.

For example, is I give the method

```
      string MyMethod(string ByteValue)
        { 

        //I want to take the hexValue and use it to look in the enumeration and return the 
         type based on the byte value


        //Can you go from an enumeration to a string?

        }


  enum Directions : byte
        {
            Left = 0x00,
            Right = 0x01,
            Up = 0x02,
            Down = 0x03,

            }
```

Comment: can you provide an example input/output pair? Aside from this you can convert enums from integers/bytes just with cast `(Directions)value` and you can get the *Name* with `.ToString()` what I don't get is why your input is a string but named *ByteValue*

Comment: I think you could simply convert `ByteValue` to int and then do something like `var direction = ((Directions)value).ToString()`

Comment: If you use the result of this function for program logic and not just to display, you should return the enum instead of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the value

```
string MyMethod(string ByteValue)
{ 
   return ((Directions)Convert.ToByte(ByteValue,16)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did end up using your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the name of the `enum` value, try [`GetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var val = Directions.Down;
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Directions), val);
```

Comment: @tennis779: Nice to hear that. Please don't forget to accept the answer you liked best (and please check your previous question to do the same).